# PHP Website Cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I have started to learn PHP a couple of weeks ago, and now I would like to create (even a simpler version would be acceptable for me) a website such as:

- www.cookiebot.com/en/start
- cookie-checker.com

So I would like to create a form where the user can type the domain from which she/he would like to know which cookies are sent/used in that website.
Whether are third party cookies or not, and so on.

On the Internet I have found several different answers to this question, some people told me is not possible to get such cookies, others told me is possible but they have not been able to explain me, and so on.

So my question is: can somebody explain me theoretically how a website like that one works?
Does PHP have a function to get cookies or cookies information from the website and let the developer read the cookies at least to know what kind of cookie it is?

Or maybe is there any way to read the cookies stored on my computer when I visit a website?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

No.

The browser explicitly saves cookies on a per-domain and even per-directory basis. When the server sets a cookie, it can specify within limitations whether a cookie is valid for subdomains or not and what path it should be valid for. However, cookies cannot be *set* cross-domain or *read* cross-domain. The browser will not send cookies back to other servers, and client-side Javascript has no access to cookies from other domains either.

In short, you cannot have a website which has access to cookies set by some other website. **And that is a good thing.** Otherwise security would be non existent on the web.

Comment: Deceze, thank you very much!
How does that kind of website work, so?

Does it uses CURL or something like that to retrieve cookies?

I am not able to explain how that kind of website work.

Comment: Yes, that site makes a request to the entered site via curl or such and simply tells you what cookies it sees. It doesn't get *your* cookies, it simply tells you what cookies any random visitor to the site would see.